# C# How to save values from a listbox into settings.settings

Tags: c#, settings.settings

How can I save values from a listbox into settings.settings and how can I load them when I start my application.

Comment: What does "settings.settings" states for? It's smth on client side of web app (e.x. JavaScript variable) or what? Need more info on this question

Comment: Properties MySettings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a key named "Setting1" in your settings.settings

To read the value of this key

```
String value = Settings.Default.Setting1;
```